# Strange output summing up values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I noted a strange thing summing up numbers in a list:

```
>>> mylist = [200.2345, 300.5, 6000000.0]
>>> sum(mylist)
6000500.7345 ==> OK
>>> mylist = [200.2345, 300.5, 200.2345]
>>> sum(mylist)
700.969 ==> OK
>>> mylist = [200.2345, 6000000.0, 200.2345]
>>> sum(mylist)  
6000400.4690000005 ==> WRONG
```

What's happening here?
Did I do something wrong or is it a bug in sum()?

Comment: Well float point number happened

Comment: This is a float problem versus a sum problem. Basically, how the data is stored in python when it comes to decimals

Comment: From python documentation: "The exactness carries over into arithmetic. In decimal floating point, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, the result is 5.5511151231257827e-017. While near to zero, the differences prevent reliable equality testing and differences can accumulate. For this reason, decimal is preferred in accounting applications which have strict equality invariants." Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: @Adib, how can I have the correct result? Sorry that my question in a duplicate. I will delate it.

Comment: @Reman  One solution I can think of is using `round()` to round up to closest possible figure. Another good solution is dividing the two numbers and seeing how close they are to the int.

Comment: @Adib dividing the two numbers and seeing how close they are to the int?

Comment: For your case, you can try this: `>>>mylist = [200.2345, 6000000.0, 200.2345] >>> int_sum = int(sum(mylist)) >>> ratio = round(int_sum/sum(mylist),2) >>> if ratio == 1.00: #Do something`

Comment: @Adib, in 2nd example (the correct output) the ration = `0.9986176278836867` and the 3rd example (the wrong output) the ratio is `0.9999999218385501` Still don't understand what I have to do and what is the difference between both

Comment: @Reman My point is that you should round to the number of significant figures you care about (for example, the accuracy should be at least 3 decimal points). Then you compare based on that rounding.

Comment: @Adib, Would this be ok? `float(decimal.Decimal("200.2345") + decimal.Decimal("300.5") + decimal.Decimal("200.2345"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108980/discussion-between-adib-and-reman).